# Active Model Serializers: Rendering array of values only renders first value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have an array of values: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I would like these to be rendered using `json_api`. I've successfully used `ActiveModelSerializers::Model` for other purposes to render a single plain Ruby object. But in this case, I have an array of objects. When rendered, AMS only renders the first object.

### Setup

#### Model

```
class Step < ActiveModelSerializers::Model
  attr_accessor :value
end
```

#### Serializer

```
class StepSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :value
end
```

#### Controller

```
class Api::StepsController < Api::BaseController

  def index
    steps = Option.pluck(:step).uniq.map { |v| Step.new(value: v) }
    render json: steps
  end

end
```

#### Output

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "step",
    "type": "step",
    "attributes": {
      "value": 1
    }
  }]
}
```

I would expect all 5 models to be rendered, but it appears only the first is being rendered.  Any ideas?

Using `active_model_serializers (0.10.7)`

Comment: Are you sure you have 5 unique entries? What does running `Option.pluck(:step).uniq` in `rails console` give you?

Comment: Yes, they are unique. Running `Option.pluck(:step).uniq.map { |v| Step.new(value: v) }` produces 5 objects, with values 1-5.

Comment: Try `render json: steps, each_serializer: StepSerializer`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you do not need this anymore, but maybe this can help someone.

I had a similar issue: in my case the issue was that I was using a resource with a `id = nil`.
It generated only a single entry! 
Once I populated the `id` with unique identifier it worked as expected.

I realized that reading the json:api format (https://jsonapi.org/format/), since one of the requirement was:

**Every resource object MUST contain an id member and a type member. The values of the id and type members MUST be strings.**

I hope this can help